# Symfony: On Custom Listener get the code snippet and file when an exception gets thrown

Tags: php, symfony, exception, httpresponse, symfony-3.3

On my symfony 3.3 when an exception gets thrown I want to override the response that gets returned. So I did my own Event Listener as it says the following piece of documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html.

But when I run it over a dev environment I want to get both the stacktrace and the line of code. I manage to get the stacktrace using the following piece of code:

```
$exception = $event->getException();
$exception->getTrace();
```

But how I can get the snippet that thows the specific exception that the default view throws?

## Edit 1: Further explanation

I mean that on the default exception throwing view I get a response something like:

```
<Exception_NAME>

in ^somefile^ as line ^Some Line^

<The php code lines where the exception has been thrown>

in ^another_somefile^ as line ^Some Line^

<The php code lines where the exception has been thrown>
```

And I want when Over dev to keep the response above either in a log file or into the view itself when I run the application over the dev environment.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. If you want to get the file which throw the exception you could use the first or second element of the `getTrace`method.

Comment: I just edited my question to explain it better.

Comment: Do you know the `profiler` of Symfony ? It's a great tool that will help you debugging your application. If you want to launch your code only in dev env you should add as dependencie of your service exception listener the parameter `kernel.environment`. If the value of this parameter is different then `dev` exit the listener to avoid code execution. What is the real purpose of your question ?